# Javascript equivalent of php mktime

Tags: javascript

Iam using mktime() function in php to get the seconds for given year,month,date and minutes as like

```
$seconds = mktime($hour,$minute,$month,$day,$year);
```

but I want to use the same in javascript...can anyone suggest me the way to use its equivalent function in javascript that takes above all parameters and returns number of seconds...I have searched so many sources but no one has given me the output.

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/mktime/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var seconds = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0).getTime() / 1000;
```

The above will give seconds since 1-1-1970. `getTime()` gives miliseconds therefore devide by 1000. Note (as Aler Close also mentioned), the month ranges from 0-11, so you might need to correct that compared to `mktime`

```
function java_mktime(hour,minute,month,day,year) {
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minutes 0, 0).getTime() / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use the Date object

```
function mktime(hour,minute,month,day,year){
  a=new Date()
  a.setHours(hour)
  a.setMinutes(minute)
  a.setDate(day)
  a.setYear(year)
  return a.getTime()/1000
}
```

Alternatively,

```
 function mktime(hour,minute,month,day,year){
   return (new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0)).getTime()/1000;
 }
```

Comment: getTime returns milliseconds and not seconds, you may divide per 1000

Comment: @Tobia: Yep, missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date object (months is a value from 0 to 11):

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
```